# Setting binding source properly in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I'd like to have a list of TextBlocks with ComboBoxes next to each of them.
The data source of ComboBoxes should be the same for every ComboBox. Each TextBlock however should contain sequent element of List
Both data source for ComboBoxs and TextBlocks are in my "settings" object. So I set DataContext of the whole window to this settings object.

Here's my problem:
Data source of TextBlock is: List called Fields, which is inside of an object called "Header" of type "Line" (which is of course inside settings object, which is my datacontext).

So, graphically:
settings(type: Settings) -  Header(type: CsvLine) - Fields(type: List of string)

Now ComboBox. Data source of every ComboBox should be a List called Tags

Graphically:
settings(type: Settings) - Tags(type: List of string)

I don't know how I should point to these locations, I tried a lot of options, but none of them work. I see just a blank window.

Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Headers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fields}"/>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tags,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have no idea what I should actually pass as ItemsSource to ItemsControl, because I think it should be common source for both TextBoxes and ComboBoxes, but their only common source is settings object - but i already set it as my DataContext.
I have used RelativeSource in ComboBox, but I'm not really sure what it's used for (although I read an article about it on MSDN). I don't know why but it's really hard for me to understand binding - I'm struggling to get anything working.

//EDIT:
Here's my Settings class - which is the type of my settings object:

```
public class Settings
{
    public CsvLine AllHeaders1
    {
        get
        {
            return _allHeaders1;
        }
    }

    public CsvLine _allHeaders1 = new CsvLine()
    {
        Fields = new List<string>()  
        { 
           "Header1" , "Header2" , "Header3" 
        }
    };

    private List<String> _tags;

    public List<String> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>() { "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3", "Tag4", "Tag5" };
        }
        set
        {
            _tags = value;
        }
    }

}
```

And here's my CsvLine class:

```
public class CsvLine
{
    public List<string> Fields = new List<string>();

    public int LineNumber;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're a million miles away. Could you post your settings object as it's difficult to provide insight from your description? For sure the binding in the TextBlock '{Binding Fields}' is wrong given that, in your description, Fields is a list of string.

Comment: Of course, I'll add it in a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm not 100% sure of what it is you want, but the following should get you started.

Firstly, you need to ensure you bind to public properties - not public members - so the CsvLine.Fields member needs to be changed to `public List<string> Fields { get { return _fields; } set { _fields = value; } }`. Also not that, if you want changes in the settings object to be reflected in the UI, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Anyway, with this in place and assigned to the DataContext of the grid, the following will display a vertical list of text blocks (showing "Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3") each with a combo box to the right containing the values "Tag1", "Tag2" ... "Tag5".

```
<Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllHeaders1.Fields}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SourceGrid, Path=DataContext.Tags}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, that's working! How did you know how it should be bound? I mean, why did you bind ItemsControl to AllHeaders.Fields? Doesn't it apply to ComboBoxes too, since they are inside of this ItemsControl? Why doesn't it just work if I do binding in the TextBlock directly to Allheaders1.Fields?

Comment: TextBlock is only able to display a single item of content and is not expecting a collection and will therefore try to call ".ToString()" on the object it's bound to. I would expect that, when you bound the Allheaders.Fields collection to the TextBlock, it displayed something like "List<'a>" (i.e. the name of the class bound to the TextBlock).
Regardless, yes, the DataContext will flow down from the ItemsControl into the ComboBox too which is why you need the long hand binding for the ComboBox ItemsSource which specifies the element to bind to and refers specifically to it's DataContext.

Comment: OK, but if you bound AllHeaders1.Fields to ItemsControl, TextBlock also receives that Bounding, but it does not display "List<string>" - it properly displays the content of this list. How does it do that?

Comment: In simple (and wildly inaccurate) terms, when you bind a collection to the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property, the ItemsControl enumerates through the collection, instantiating new ItemTemplates for each item in the collection and setting the DataContext of that ItemTemplate to the item itself (not the entire collection). Which is why the TextBox.Text binding is simply '{Binding}' (i.e. bind to the current DataContext, which in this case is a string). Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, very good explanation, now I understand it. But I still do not get it why ComboBox has Binding ElementName=SourceGrid, Path=DataContext.Tags. You set the source of binding to the grid in the window. Now, the path is set to DataContext.Tags, which in this case means SourceGrid.Tags? No, it can't be that way, so why is there ElementName=SourceGrid? I thought it's used to bind to other controls, but in this case we want to bind to a List of string called Tags. How does this binding work?

Comment: As per the above, the DataContext at the position of the ComboBox is the header string ("Header1", "Header2", etc). So, from a string, we have no way of binding to the tag collection.
Instead, we use an "anchor" to get back to the full Settings object. The anchor in this instance is the Grid which has the Settings object as it's DataContext. Therefore, we name the grid and use it in the ElementName part of the binding and set the Path part of the binding to 'DataContext.Tags'.

Comment: Another great explanation, thank you very much for your help, now the code is clear.